# Sometimes MySQL stops using right index

Tags: mysql, database, indexing

Several times I had such situation: query that has worked quickly started work in 1000-10_000 times slower in one moment when there was no changes. MySQL stops using proper index and I have to use `FORCE INDEX(..)`. It happens with queries to big tables with 10-300M records.

MySQL: 5.6.23 (AWS RDS, db.r3.xlarge)

There is the last issue:

table1 (175M records)

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `site_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `index_table1_on_site_id_and_..._and_type_and_...` (`site_id`,`...`,`type`,`...`),
  KEY `index_table1_on_created_at_and_site_id` (`created_at`,`site_id`),
  KEY `index_table1_on_site_id_and_type_and_created_at_and_...` (`site_id`,`type`,`created_at`,`...`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `index_table1_on_site_and_type_and_..._and_created` (`site_id`,`type`,`..._id`,`created_at`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=... DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

table2 (2M records)

```
CREATE TABLE `table2` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `table1_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ...
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=... DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

request:

```
SELECT  `table1`.* FROM `table1` 
INNER JOIN `table2` ON `table2`.`table1_id` = `table1`.`id` 
WHERE `table1`.`type` IN ('...', '...') 
  AND `table1`.`site_id` = ... 
  AND (table1.created_at >= '...') 
  AND (table1.created_at <= '...')  
ORDER BY `table1`.`id` DESC LIMIT 30 offset 0;
```

was ~10-80ms
now > 420 sec

request with `FORCE INDEX`:

```
SELECT  `table1`.* FROM `table1` USE INDEX (`index_table1_on_site_id_and_type_and_created_at_and_...`) 
INNER JOIN `table2` ON `table2`.`table1_id` = `table1`.`id` 
WHERE `table1`.`type` IN ('...', '...') 
  AND `table1`.`site_id` = ... 
  AND (table1.created_at >= '...') 
  AND (table1.created_at <= '...')  
ORDER BY `table1`.`id` DESC LIMIT 30 offset 0;
```

~85 ms

EXPLAINE:
without `FORCE`

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: table1
         type: index
possible_keys: PRIMARY,index_table1_on_site_id_and_..._and_type_and_...,index_table1_on_created_at_and_site_id,index_table1_on_type,index_table1_on_site_id_and_type_and_created_at_and_...,index_table1_on_site_and_type_and_..._and_created
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: NULL
         rows: 9257179
        Extra: Using where
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: table2
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: ...
          key: ...
      key_len: 4
          ref: db.table1.id
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using index
```

with `FORCE`

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: table1
         type: range
possible_keys: index_table1_on_site_id_and_type_and_created_at_and_...
          key: index_table1_on_site_id_and_type_and_created_at_and_...
      key_len: 88
          ref: NULL
         rows: 499
        Extra: Using index condition; Using filesort
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: table2
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: ...
          key: ...
      key_len: 4
          ref: db.table1.id
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using index
```

Is there any solutions to avoid such unpredictable MySQL behaviour? I can't add `FORCE INDEX` to all requests, what to do?

P.S.:

```
SELECT * FROM `table1` 
INNER JOIN `table2` ON `table2`.`table1_id` = `table1`.`id` 
WHERE `table1`.`site_id` = ... ;
```

returns just 122 records

P.S.S: Crazy, but request works faster for wider time period

```
AND (table1.created_at >= '2016-07-01') AND (table1.created_at <= '2016-07-07)
```

420 sec

```
AND (table1.created_at >= '2016-06-01') AND (table1.created_at <= '2016-07-07)
```

85ms

Comment: mysql can decide that a full table scan will be more efficient than using an index. if it decides that, then you only choices are to rewrite the query to trick it into thinking otherwise, or forcing the index.

Comment: - it's strange that MySQL can prefer to scan 9M rows instead of 499

Comment: - it's scary that MySQL can work with indexes properly and in one moment decides do not use index any more

Comment: What version?  Can you provide `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` for those queries.

Comment: What percent of the table is fetched?

Answer (score 1):

If the tables have changed, you can try running `ANALYZE TABLE` (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/analyze-table.html) to update the stats synchronously. InnoDB [persists optimizer stats](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-persistent-stats.html) which has some [limitations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-restrictions.html).

Based on the date ranges, I also wonder if it would be just as fast if you did

```
AND (table1.created_at >= '2016-06-01') AND (table1.created_at <= '2016-06-07)'
```

assuming that the older data has more stable stats, and it's not the size that makes the difference.

Comment: Tables have not been changed

Comment: I run `ANALYZE TABLE`, but it has not helped

Comment: Interesting, query with `created_at >= '2016-06-01' AND created_at <= '2016-06-07'` and `created_at >= '2016-07-01' AND created_at <= '2016-07-07'` works slow, but with `created_at >= '2016-06-01' AND created_at <= '2016-07-07'` works fast

Comment: Does the `EXPLAIN` change?

Comment: @RickJames , yes, queries use different indexes: query for a week uses `index_table1_on_site_id_and_..._and_type_and_...` (filters just by `site_id`), query for a month uses `index_table1_on_site_id_and_type_and_created_at_and_...` (filters by `site_id`, `type`, `created_at`)